# Logic App Collection Functions

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am setting conditions on a Slack Connector in my Logic App.  I want Slack to notify me if a key actions fail.

```
"conditions": [
                {
                    "expression": "@or(equals(actions('step1').status,'Failed'),equals(actions('step2').status,'Failed'),equals(actions('step3').status,'Failed'))"
                }
            ]
```

I would prefer to check an overall workflow status for failed or be able to have an "any" function on the action collection.  `ex. @any(actions(a=>a.status=='Failed')` Is there a better way currently for me to do the expression above?

Answer (score -2):

There is no support for higher order functions in Logic Apps today.

However, you can use a workflow action in order to encapsulate the logic in a child logic app. The parent logic app can then have a condition on the output of the nested logic app run. That is, the child logic app would execute step1, step2 and step3, and if any of the steps fail the run will be marked as failed. The parent logic app would then check the run status of the child logic app run.

The following blog post provides a good overview of nested logic app functionality and has a small sample on how to return data back to the parent logic app
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2015/05/31/using-nested-azure-logic-apps-or-invoking-flows-from-another-logic-app/